# SQL pattern that matches all strings consisting of two words separated by one space character

Tags: sql, pattern-matching, wildcard

What do I write in my LIKE statement so that it matches all strings consisting of two words separated by one space?

Comment: What database are you using? Are you really *forced* into using LIKE?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008. And I think I'm supposed to use LIKE because that's the point of the exercise - learn how to use LIKE. We haven't studied anything advanced.

Comment: Homework questions are allowed, but please read this first: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this:

```
WHERE x LIKE '%_ _%'
  AND x NOT LIKE '% % %'
```

Note that it will be slow! If your table can be large and you need to do this often, you may want to rethink your design.

Comment: @MarkByers Could you explain a bit more? The second line says "not three words"? What if there are 4 words? Why do you do the underscores in the first line?

Comment: @user763852 Don't just copy&paste. Try to understand. Just my 2 cents. Or is everything clear for you?

Comment: @tombom: First line says "Contains at least three characters and contains a space in the middle". Second line says "Does not contain two spaces".

Comment: @MarkByers Ah, yes, thanks. It's early in the morning for me :)

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can try matching "[zero or more charactersInYourString][space][zero or more charactersInYourString]".

For example

`"[a-zA-Z0-9]*[[:space:]][a-zA-Z0-9]*"`

for a string that is composed of lower case, upper case letters and numbers seperated by a space.

Comment: There was no mention of sql server 2008 at the moment i was replying. It probably doesn't work because sql server 2008 does not understand this definition of the "space" class. In this case you could use a simple space between the two charactersInYourString definitions or one of sql server's symbols for whitespace from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174214.aspx)